# php contact form mistake in code?

Tags: php

I am beginner in php and I tried to programe an easy contact form. My question is: whats wrong with my code? I cant seem to find any mistake with formating or anything... This is my code:

contact.php:

```
    ...page content...
    <div class="contact">              
            <form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
             <fieldset>
                  <label for="name">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />   
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />        
              <label for="message">Message:</label>
              <textarea name="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" />

             </fieldset>
              </form>
</div>

...page content...
```

send_mail.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: My website'; 
    $to = 'someone@email.cz'; 
    $subject = 'My contact form message';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {              
         if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
             echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
           } else {                                            
             echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
           } 
    }
?>
```

I am getting the "Something went wrong" message, which means taht mail() returned false but I dont know why. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have a `backslash` in your `else {` near the bottom

Comment: I corrected the backslash but the error is still there... but thanks for the notice

Comment: Is the email being delivered? The standard SMTP server is localhost. If you haven't changed the SMTP server, is there an email server running on the same machine?

Comment: You will not be able to shoot email from localhost. Try to upload the script on online server. It must be working fine.

Comment: The function `mail` does not send email, but "connects" to a mail server and tells what to do. So your error might be because the server refuses it or simply there is no mail server on your machine. (The mail server is NOT the web server)

Comment: It didnt occur to me that the problem could be that I cant send an email from my localhost server... I take a look on that...

Comment: The form sends the email fine, but getting same error. Must be a `headers` related issue.

Comment: That must be because of mail function, I think you don't have mail server setup on your computer. You can use sendmail, if you're working on linux.

Comment: Isn't the fourth parameter for `mail` headers for the email? In which case, it might be complaining because the `From:` isn't an actual email address - you could try removing that parameter from the call to `mail` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Usual way of using `mail()` function is `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);` there are no mentions of headers and what @andrewsi mentioned about the `From:` not being an actual email address.

Comment: @Smajl See my answer below, let me know of your results. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with running scripts on your local computer. Most computers will not have an email server and be configured to send email from that server.

For the PHP mail function to work, your computer must have an email server set up.
You can either look at online hosting with email support or for local testing, install a test mail server.

There is a bit about non mac OS's at the end. I've had some luck with this in the past.

If your on windows, this is probably better: http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Answer (score 2):

Your headers need to contain proper [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
Using only `From: My website` stands at going to Spam.
Using an Email => `From: $email\r\n` will work better.

**Give this a try, tested.**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$to = 'your_email@somewhere.com'; 
$subject = 'My contact form message';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if(empty($email)) {
die("Something went wrong, go back and try again!"); 
}
elseif (isset($_POST['email'])) {
mail($to,$email,$body,$headers);
echo "<p>Your message has been sent!</p>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 . To made work this code.you should send your mail from any domain.

```
for example: you should have a live website thru that domain email id only send mail to
others
```

2 . use PHP-MAILER coding for sending mail.just download from net and make changes and use